# How to read `minSdkVersion` in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, versioning

I set `minSdkVersion` in flavor:

```
android {
 buildTypes {
    release {
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
    }

    productFlavors {
            myFlavor {
                minSdkVersion 19
            }
        }
}
```

**Accroding this:**

[image]

I want to build `versionCode`, that contains `minSdkVersion` in the `versionCode`:

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        // get the version code of each flavor
        variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode =  variant.versionCode * 100000 + minSdkVersion(?) * 1000 + defaultConfig.versionCode
    }
```

How can I access to `minSdkVersion` in this script?

I tried:

- `variant.minSdkVersion`
- `android.minSdkVersion`
- `project.minSdkVersion`
- `project.android.minSdkVersion`

But have no luck.

Comment: What are you trying to do? How is the image you posted related to setting the minimumSdkLevel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def api = variant.mergedFlavor.minSdkVersion.apiLevel
    ....
}
```